# How to calculate Mean-squared displacement from a file in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the mean-squared displacements of atoms from a file in C++. I have the file where the atoms positions in each time step is written like below where 1..5 column respectively represents timestep, atom, and x,y,z co-ordinates of that atom.

```
Timestep = 0000000

0000000   Fe      0     0     0
0000000   Fe      0     1     0
......    ..      ..    ..    ..

Timestep = 1000000

1000000   Fe      0     0     1
1000000   Fe      0     0     2
.......   ..      ..    ..    ..
And so on...
```

What I want is the length of the vector difference of the atoms and the time difference and then calculate MSD in a separate file (say 'msd.txt') where the 1st column would be in this particular case 1000000 and the 2nd column would be ([001 - 000]^2 + [002 - 010]^2)/2 i.e., squared of the displacement of the atoms. The displacement of individual atom is simply the length of the vector difference of individual atom. As in this case the 1st atom moves to [001] position from [000] position. A simple C++ code would be really helpful in this regard as I am really new in C++. I have written a sample code for this as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int Natoms = 16; //Number of atoms


double length() const  // computes the length of the vector
  {
    return sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
  }


int main ()
{
  ofstream oFile("msd.txt");
  oFile << "# time  msd" << endl;
  vector<vector<double> > table;  // stores 'dr' for all the atoms and different time steps
   for (int t = 0; t < MaxSteps; t++)
   {
        timestep = 1000
        ct = (t+1)*timestep;
        vector<double> column;
        vector<double> rt; vector<double> r0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Natoms; i++)
        {
                double dr = rt[iTarget] - r0[iOrigin];
                double dr2 = dr * dr;
                column.push_back(dr2);
        }
        double sum_of_dr2 = 0. ; double MSD = 0. ;
        for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = column.begin(); it != column.end(); ++it)
                sum_of_dr2 += *it;

        MSD = sum_of_dr2 * (1./(double)Natoms);
        table.push_back(column);
        oFile << ct << "\t" << MSD << endl;
   }
  oFile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

But I don't know how to read from the given file so that I can have the `length` of the vector difference for each atom stored in `dr` in the sample code. Here `length` of the vector of 1st and 2nd atom after a time step 1000000 would be sqrt((0-0)^2+(0-0)^2+(0-1)^2) and sqrt((0-0)^2+(0-0)^2+(0-2)^2) resp. These data should be stored in `dr[i]` (say) where `i` = 1,2,..N is the no of atom.

Comment: it is not really clear what is the question. You want to know how to read numbers from a file? I would actually suggest that you abstract your problem a bit more. For sure your coding problem is not specific for atoms

Comment: Search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ read file struct".  Searching the internet first is always a good idea.

Comment: @tobi303: I have edited a bit my question. Please have a look at it. I know the algorithm a little bit but having problem in how to perform the vector difference for all the atoms syntactically.

Comment: Your sample code won't compile - it has got many syntax problems - work on that first. Second, for starters - don't get the data from a file but hardcode some values so you can check easily, by hand, if your code calculate good values. Then if it works - start implementing reading data from file.

Comment: @HalnyHultaj: Yes, I know the sample code wont compile. It was just for the overview how the algorithm should work. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: can you please try to ask the question without using the word "atoms"? I mean it doesnt really matter what the number in the vectors represent and imho that just adds confusion. I dont understand at all what you mean with "how to read from the given file so that I can have the length of the vector difference for each atom stored in dr in the sample code." What is "the length of the vector difference" ?

Comment: Well the 'atoms' is just for representation. If a atom(or whatever) goes from a vector position (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) the 'the length of the vector difference' is simply sqrt((0-1)^2+(0-1)^2+(0-1)^2). For details of MSD calculations you can see the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_displacement

Comment: @tobi303: The following snippet does the vector length calculations but only for one point and one time step. I hope it's bit clear now. Sorry for making it difficult
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double Distance(double dX0, double dY0, double dX1, double dY1)
{
    return sqrt((dX1 - dX0)*(dX1 - dX0) + (dY1 - dY0)*(dY1 - dY0));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // Calculate two distances
    cout << "Distance = " << Distance(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) << endl;
    cout << "Distance = " << Distance(2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0) << endl;

    return 0;
}

Comment: @baban code in comments is (almost) impossible to read.

Comment: @tobi303: Sorry. Have a look here: http://xoax.net/cpp/ref/cpp_examples/incl/distance_points_plane/

Comment: ok. you have to take care with terminology, because usually the "length" of a `std::vector` is its size, ie number of elements, while you mean the norm of a vector, ie lenght in a mathematical sense. However, I still dont understand what is the question, as it seems you know how to calculate the norm. Let me ask again: Do you want to know how to read the number from a file?

Comment: @tobi303: Yes, you're right. I know, in principle, to calculate the norm. But how can I read the data form the file and store the norm of the vector for many particle/or atom in a vector or array or so? What could be the syntax for that in C++? I need to make a loop over timestep, no of atoms/particles and store respectively their norms which changes over time.

Comment: you still dont get my point. There is no syntax in C++ for atoms! You have to split your problem into smaller subtask, Instead of "how can I read the data form the file and store the norm of the vector for many particle/or atom in a vector or array or so?" you should ask 1) How can I read the numbers from a file? and only then 2) how can I calculate the norm and store it in a vector and only then move on to the next strep. Once you do this, you will (hopefully) realize that reading numbers from a file needs zero knowledge of atoms :P

Comment: No No I completely understood your point. Forget about 'atoms' as I told this is just for representation purpose. Since I have to calculate the norm of many (particle/object/atom) things that why I chose to call it with a particular name (say atom), that's it! Now let's focus what you asked in 1) and 2). How could I do that? 1) read the numbers from the given type of file format and then 2)store those values (after calculating norm)?